# Remove last 3 classes on one element?

Tags: jquery

I've searched but haven't had much luck.

I'm trying to remove the last 3 classes of this element with jquery and not sure how to do it.

The names of these classes will change based on the results of a quiz so I can't just do a simple .removeClass(x,x,x)

```
<section class="container books-home alphabet prereading result">
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var allButLastThree = this.className.split(/\s/).slice(0,-3).join(' ');
```

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n538R/).

Or if you want to stay with a more jQuery approach:

```
$(this).attr('class',function(index,classes){
    return classes.split(/\s/).slice(0,-3).join(' ');
});
```

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n538R/1/).

References:

- [jQuery `attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Great. This helps me out a ton! I will have to read up on the references.